# Regex to detect nested area

Tags: regex

Given this text :

```
[start block1]
[end block1]
lorem
[start block2]
ipsum
[start block2_1]
[end block2_1]
dolor
[end block2]
```

Is it possible with a regex to match block1 & block2 without block2_1.

Of course we cannot rely on the name of the block but only that fact that he is nested in another block.

Comment: It is a dumb down version but like I said if you dont rely on the name of the blocks this should be enough info to solve this problem...

Comment: so there will never be input like: `[start block1] ... [start block1] ... [end block1] ... [end block1]` (nesting with the same tags)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[start (\w+)\].*?\[end \1\]
```

As long as you aren't repeating any block name, you should be fine. `\1` will match the name of the block you've started, and capture anything inside. Make sure to use the dot-all option (or single-line), `/s`, or the `[\s\S]*` hack if your flavor doesn't support it (like JavaScript).

In PHP, use this code:

```
preg_match_all('/\[start (\w+)\].*?\[end \1\]/s', $str, $matches);
```

You can then easily get the names:

```
$area_names = $matches[1];
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/OsbSt

Comment: this matches everything but lorem

Comment: @Paté - lorem isn't inside a block. Maybe I didn't understand the question correctly - what are you expecting? Try to edit the question and explain that, and what language you are using...

Comment: This would be my answer too, if I wasn't confused by the "Of course we cannot rely on the name of the block..." statement. I simply don't know whether this solution is applicable to the (scarce) specification.

Comment: I know but When I run your regex on the text above it matches everything but lorem.

Comment: @Paté - Right, but with only two matches - one for each block.

Comment: @Paté - Using the regex above, the block name is capture to group `$1`, and nested blocks (with other names) are skipped over.

Comment: @Paté - No problem! A recursive alternative might be `\[start (\w+)\](?:[^\[\]]|(?R))*+\[end \1\]` , but that is less supported, and doesn't handle other `[]` characters or tags very well.

Comment: @Kobi do you have any idea of what needs to be done to make that regex work with PHP ?